# Titanium build error ,docs does not exist

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I created a module in Titanium and try to build into zip then i am getting an error like below .

```
    C:\Users\sarathraj\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.1.GA\module\android\build.xml:409: C:\Users\sarathraj\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace2\modtest\build\docs does not exist.
```

I checked the build.xml file in line 409.

```
 <zip destfile="${dist}/${module.id}-android-${manifest.version}.zip">
        <zipfileset file="${module.jar}" prefix="${zip.prefix}"/>
        <zipfileset file="manifest" prefix="${zip.prefix}"/>
        <zipfileset file="timodule.xml" prefix="${zip.prefix}"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${docs}" prefix="${zip.prefix}/documentation"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${lib}" includes="**/*.jar" prefix="${zip.prefix}/lib"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${ti.module.root}" includes="platform/**" excludes="platform/README" prefix="${zip.prefix}"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${ti.module.root}" includes="LICENSE" prefix="${zip.prefix}"/>
        <zipfileset dir="${ti.module.root}" includes="example/**" prefix="${zip.prefix}"/>
    </zip>
```

Any Solution to solve this

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  Manually creating the docs folder fixed it for me.